# Xcode AMSlideMenu Opening Left menu only with a button, disabling swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, amslidemenu

This might sound like a weird request but I've been using the AMSlideMenu (which is fantastic) https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu

But on one of my specific projects I need to be able to open the left side menu only using a button.

Now I have a button that's currently working to open and close the menu, but for this specific project I need to use swipe gestures, so I would need to disable accessing the menu via swipes.

I've been looking at the methods that are within the AMSlideMenu files, but I can't figure out how to disable the swiping.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've read the documentation in the [link](https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu), you could notice they stated that you have to import `"UIViewController+AMSlideMenu.h"` on your pushed view controller and then call `[self disableSlidePanGestureForLeftMenu];` on your `viewDidLoad` method (or wherever you want). I've tried it with the example they've provided and it works.

[image]

**Update:**
For iOS 8+ you should call this method on `viewWillAppear` and not `viewDidLoad` [as mentioned here](http://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu/issues/115).

Comment: For iOS 8 and 8+ you should call this method on viewWillAppear and not viewDidLoad (tested and working). Source: https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu/issues/115